# how to fix RefererDeniedMapError on google map JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My google map JavaScript API does not work any more. it seems google blocked me. look at [this link](http://hamyaraniran.ir/map.php). in console i get below error:

```
Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererDeniedMapError
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-denied-map-error
_.Ic @ js?key=AIzaSyDyECNnY4HOjiGu7m0f43yvlNe7Y9AgRcs&callback=initMap:53
```

here are my google console screenshots:
[image: google console page 1]
[image: google console page 2]

here is my codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
       /* Set the size of the div element that contains the map */
      #map {
        height: 400px;  /* The height is 400 pixels */
        width: 100%;  /* The width is the width of the web page */
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <!--The div element for the map -->
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
// Initialize and add the map
function initMap() {
  // The location of Uluru
  var uluru = {lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036};
  // The map, centered at Uluru
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: uluru});
  // The marker, positioned at Uluru
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
}
    </script>
    <!--Load the API from the specified URL
    * The async attribute allows the browser to render the page while the API loads
    * The key parameter will contain your own API key (which is not needed for this tutorial)
    * The callback parameter executes the initMap() function
    -->
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDyECNnY4HOjiGu7m0f43yvlNe7Y9AgRcs&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

how can i fix it?!

Comment: What domain is the page running on?  (your [link](http://hamyaraniran.ir/map.php) doesn't work, at least for me)

Comment: @geocodezip , hi , i append my codes to question. please help me. this link works fine in iran, i don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open the documentation link mentioned in the error message and read what it says

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-denied-map-error

> Your application was blocked for non-compliance with the Google Maps Platform Terms of Service, following several email notifications. To appeal the block and have your implementation reviewed, please complete this form. You will receive a response via email within a few business days.

So, the only option to unblock your web site is submit a web form to Google as mentioned in the documentation.

I hope this helps!

Comment: hi, thank you so much, but i submitted this form couple days ago and google did not answer me.

Comment: Not sure, but probably it somewhat related to this list https://enterprise.google.com/maps/terms/us/maps_integrator_territory.html